# Java conversion HEX to IEEE 754 32 bit value...?

Tags: java

Can any help me in converting a hex value to IEE 754 32 bit value?

Comment: Can you add some examples for sample input/output?

Answer (score 0):

Go for [`longBitsToDouble`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29)

```
public static double longBitsToDouble(long bits)
```

> Returns the double value corresponding
>   to a given bit representation. The
>   argument is considered to be a
>   representation of a floating-point
>   value according to the IEEE 754
>   floating-point "double format" bit
>   layout.

**Parameters:**  `bits - any long integer.`

**Returns:** `the double floating-point value with the same bit pattern.`

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods available in the JDK 6 `Double` class. Consider a look at the [Javadoc of the Double class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html).